# Python lambda expression - string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, exception, lambda

I am trying to use data from one json file to update another. In trying to be efficient for searching, I'm attempting to use a lambda expression to locate the correct record to update.

The goal is to be able to most efficiently update the "PreviousMappings" key.

Code:

```
for p in Path('jobs/data').glob('*.json'):
        with open(p, 'r') as f:
            print('Loaded - ', f.name)
            jdata = json.load(f)
            for j in jdata['Mappings']:
                jc = j['Job Code']
                with open('newdata/jobs.json', 'r+') as s:
                    print('Loaded - ', s.name)
                    data = json.load(s)
                    found = list(filter(lambda x:x['Jobcode'] == jc, data)) #throws exception
```

JSON:

```
      {
"JobCodes": [
            {
                "Bid Code": "123-456",
                "Description": "JOB DESCRIPTION",
                "Jobcode": "ABC123",
                "PreviousMappings": ""
            }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So, for every entry in the "Mappings" key in the set of files, you want to update the "PreviousMappings" key in "jobs.json".  Right?  What are you storing in the new key?  You should just open that second file once, outside of the loop.  You really don't need to worry about the search -- that's not your bottleneck here.

Comment: I need to take data from every Mapping entry that has a job code that matches in the JobCodes/JobCode of the second file. I was trying to eliminate as many for loops as possible by using the lambda, but you're right - I could do this by only opening the second file once, find all the matches and update them - still need to find the matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you're asking, but you might consider a different approach.

```
data = json.load( open('newdata/jobs.json', 'r')  )

for p in Path('jobs/data').glob('*.json'):
    with open(p, 'r') as f:
        print('Loaded - ', f.name)
        jdata = json.load(f)
        for j in jdata['Mappings']:
            jc = j['Job Code']
            for k in data:
                if k['Jobcode'] == jc:
                    k['PreviousMappings'] = "something"
                    break

json.dump( open('newdata/jobs.json','w'), data )
```

If you have a LOT of files, you might consider building an index, so you can do a direct lookup.  For example (untested):

```
data = json.load( open('newdata/jobs.json', 'r')  )
dindex = {}
for k in data:
    dindex[k['Jobcode']] = k
```

Now you don't have to search -- Python will do it:

```
        for j in jdata['Mappings']:
            jc = j['Job Code']
            if jc in dindex:
                dindex[jc]['PreviousMappings'] = "something"
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will test this out. There are only about 12 files of "old" data that I need to bring in. Each one contains about 100-300 entries.

Comment: just fyi - dindex = {}
for k in data:
    dindex[k['Jobcode']] = k
Gives me the same error that this post started with :)

Comment: That suggests that your input JSON doesn't look like what you showed us.  You should `print(k)` inside the `for` loop and see what the data really looks like.

Comment: Ugh.... k = "JobCodes"

Comment: So. your `jobs.json` file does not contain what you think it contains....

Comment: Yeah... just linted it to make sure there was no corruption - all valid json. Doing print(data) shows me the entire JSON content of the file. Will dig around a bit

Comment: I figured it out..... embarrassing. 
for k in data['JobCodes']:
        dindex[k['Jobcode']] = k

Just left out the parent (smh) Time for a beer.